# Removing Grub from Windows 10 + Zorin Dual Boot

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, zorin

I'm having some trouble removing grub from my dual boot laptop!

I can't boot from the USB Windows media to access the terminal to type in the boot rec /fixmbr etc command.

It seems to be that Grub is some how overriding my UEFI BIOS settings, because my boot order is USB first, but it still won't boot from USB.

When installing Zorin on my computer I didn't turn secure boot off, so on the grub menu screen, the option for Windows is Windows Boot Manager and not Windows 10. This could be causing some problems.

I also held shift down and clicked Start to launch the recovery settings on Windows. I ran the command on the terminal in there, but it didn't work.